# How to parse a nested json in classes with python

Tags: python, json, class

How do I parse a nested JSON in classes with python with the same key?

I have tried this:

```
class RowCol(BaseModel):
    Row1 : int
    Row2 : int
    Col1 : int
    Col2 : int

class Item(BaseModel):
    UseROI: bool
    Comment: str
    ROI : List[RowCol]

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    SaveImageResult: bool
    description: Optional[str] = None
    OCR_ROI : List[Item]
```

Then, I got this:

```
{
  "SaveImageResult": true,
  "description": "string",
  "OCR_ROI": [
    {
      "UseROI": true,
      "Comment": "string",
      "ROI": [
        {
          "Row1": 0,
          "Row2": 0,
          "Col1": 0,
          "Col2": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

However, the data I want has the same key, with a different value:

```
{
  "SaveImageResult": false,
  "description": "string",
  "OCR_ROI": [
    {
      "UseROI": true,
      "Comment": "",
      "ROI": {
        "Row1": 0,
        "Col1": 0,
        "Row2": 200,
        "Col2": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "UseROI": false,
      "Comment": "",
      "ROI": {
        "Row1": 1,
        "Col1": 0,
        "Row2": 200,
        "Col2": 200
      }
    }
  ]
```

How do I solve this?

I try `Optional[]` instead of `List[]` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes, but I think this is what you are look for.

For more question, please use comments.

#### Code

**Note:** (1) Like in your code, I am not defining class variables but instance variable using `__init__`. Defining variables at class levels could lead to data corruptions in this case, so try to avoid them !

(2) In the question, BaseModel is not defined so I took and liberty to assume it as below and also import some necessary imports

```py
from typing import List, Optional, Text

class BaseModel:
    pass

class RowCol(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, Row1: int, Row2: int, Col1: int, Col2: int):
        self.Row1 = Row1
        self.Row2 = Row2
        self.Col1 = Col1
        self.Col2 = Col2

class Item(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, UseROI: bool, Comment: str, ROI: List[RowCol]):
        self.UseROI = UseROI
        self.Comment = Comment
        self.ROI = ROI

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, SaveImageResult: bool, OCR_ROI: List[Item], description: Optional[Text]):
        self.SaveImageResult = SaveImageResult
        self.OCR_ROI = OCR_ROI
        self.description = description
```

In python `false` & `true` are not valid. You need to convert them to `True` or `False`. If you have `data` or input in string or json format then use `json.loads` to convert the whole json into Python dict object.

#### Data

```py
data = {
  "SaveImageResult": False,
  "description": "string",
  "OCR_ROI": [
    {
      "UseROI": True,
      "Comment": "",
      "ROI": {
        "Row1": 0,
        "Col1": 0,
        "Row2": 200,
        "Col2": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "UseROI": False,
      "Comment": "",
      "ROI": {
        "Row1": 1,
        "Col1": 0,
        "Row2": 200,
        "Col2": 200
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Transformation

Below is the python code transformation (data -> python objects)

```py
for i in range(len(data['OCR_ROI'])):
    data['OCR_ROI'][i]['ROI'] = RowCol(**data['OCR_ROI'][i]['ROI'])
    data['OCR_ROI'][i] = Item(**data['OCR_ROI'][i])

final_object = ItemList(**data)
```

### Testing

After above transformation, I am testing

```py
>>> print(final_object.description)
string

>>> print(final_object.OCR_ROI[0].ROI.Col2)
200

>>> print(final_object.OCR_ROI[1].ROI.Row1)
1
```